# Can't use Selenium WebDriver in another file in Python

Tags: python, selenium, object, selenium-webdriver

I have created a method to generate a Webdriver object in **WebDriverFactory.py**:

```
#!python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

def generer_chrome_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    return driver
```

And when I want to use this Webdriver object in the another file **test.py**, no Webdriver methods appear:

```
#!python
import webdriverFactory

driver = webdriverFactory.generer_chrome_driver
driver. --> no methods
```

But if I do the same thing directly in **test.py**, then I have access to all the Webdriver methods like .get(url) :

```
#!python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('www.google.fr')
```

I'm new in Python, I don't know if it's a subtlety of the language that I don't see...
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have both files in the same directory (or ˋWebDriver.pyˋ is somewhere else in the ˋPYTHONPATHˋ).

In that case, you may just be missing the parentheses after generer_chrome_driver.

```
driver = webdriverFactory.generer_chrome_driver()
```

If you are relying on your IDE to show you the available methods, it may mislead you. Sometimes just the auto completion fails, but you can enter the method name manually, save the file and try to run the script afterwards and it will tell you if the method is really unavailable.